# What can I do to add new contacts to iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone

Why can't I add new contacts in my agenda iPhone 4? Every time when I want to write the name of a new person, my phone doesn't show the "keyboard".

Comment: Could you clarify? can you attach some screenshots of the issue you're facing?

Answer (score 1):

Put the device in Airplane mode, power it off, then try using notes.app to type. If that works, open the contacts app and try to edit a contact.

If that all works, you can turn off airplane mode and try again. If contacts still fails, you have issues with your database or online sync for contacts.